# Cutting a string when a specific character is found

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc

I am making a function that "cuts" a string when it finds a certain character but im getting some king of bug and i cant find what is failing. The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cut(char *src, char sep){
   int i = 0;
   
   while(++i < strlen(src) && *src && *src != sep)
      src++;
   
   *src = '\0';
    
   return i;
}

int main(void){
   
   char *line = (char *) malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(line, "#defineABC12");

   printf("%s\n", line);
   cut(line, '1');
   printf("%s\n", line);

   return 0;
}
```

If my logic dont fails, the expected output should be something like this:

```
#defineABC12
#defineABC
```

But instead im getting this:

```
#defineABC12
#defin
```

I dont know if this changes anything but im using GCC in a x86_64 machine

Comment: `strtok(line, "1");` will do the job. Or you could use `strchr` to find the character, and if the return value is not NULL, set the character to `'\0'`

Comment: Assuming you can't use standard library functions... Your cut function is incrementing src while looking for the delimiter but you while loop checks its position by `++i < strlen(src)` and `strlen(src)` is getting shorter and shorter while i is getting bigger and bigger.  You need to store `strlen(src)` before you start modifying src.  Like this: https://onlinegdb.com/S1bFq0IrP

Comment: You really don't need `++i < strlen(src)` or even the variable i at all, unless you really need to return the number of character the modified string has (which you could get by calling strlen() on the modified string): https://onlinegdb.com/ryydj0UrD.

Comment: `while(++i < strlen(src) && *src && *src != sep)`. Wow that is a horrible line of code! Slow because of the constant `strlen` calls. Redundant because of the `*str` and confusing because of the `++i` at the start.

Comment: Actually returning the place where you cut it (the length of the modified string) isn't helpful because that doesn't tell you if it was modified at all unless you knew the unmodified string's length ahead of time.  So you might want to return a pointer to the rest of the string (after the delimiter) if you replace something and NULL if you don't. (which is pretty much what strtok() does).  Or, if you return a valid string (not NULL) regardless, you might return a pointer to the rest of the string if you replace and the \0 at the end of the string if you don't: https://onlinegdb.com/S1dMCRLrv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with your loop expression.

```
while(++i < strlen(src) && *src && *src != sep)
      src++;
```

You measure the length of the string in every loop iteration, however it starts getting the string length starting at the `src` pointer. Every loop iteration you increment the pointer, therefore string length changes with every iteration. The following table illustrates what you measure.

```
i src          len
= ============ ===
0 #defineABC12 12
1 defineABC12  11
2 efineABC12   10
...
```

Therefore your loop exits before you expect it.

In general you do not need this 'i' business. Every string in 'c' is terminated by a null character, therefore '*str' is enough in your case, the following should work perfectly:

```
while(*src && *src != sep)
      src++;
```

In other cases when you need the string length you should get it before the loop, for example

```
int len = strlen(src);
int i = 0;
while(i <= len && src[i] != sep)
   i++;
src[i-1] = 0;
```

Comment: @user3386109 you are correct, i fixed the code.  'i <= len' will fix it. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to simplify things is to limit the number if things you increment within your loop. You are incrementing `i`, you don't need to also increment the pointer `src`, simply use index notation, e.g. `src[i]` to work down the string. This will allow you to simplify your `cut()` function to:

```
int cut (char *src, char sep)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    for (; src[i] && src[i] != sep; i++) {}
    
    src[i] = '\0';
        
    return i;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

In that case your result is:

```
$ ./bin/cutstr
#defineABC12
#defineABC
```

If you can simplify the number of moving parts -- you help keep the logic straight.

You can also accomplish the same thing without an index simply incrementing the pointer, e.g.

```
int cut (char *src, char sep)
{
    char *p = src;
    
    for (; *p && *p != sep; p++) {}
            
    *p = '\0';
        
    return p - src;
}
```

(same result and both return `10`)

Or, since you include `string.h`, let `strchr()` do the work, e.g.

```
int cut (char *src, char sep)
{
    char *p = strchr (src, sep);
    
    if (p) {
        *p = 0;
        return p - src;
    }
    
    return strlen(src);
}
```

(result is the same)

Let me know if you have any questions.